# how to convert Sun 10-04-19 date to 10-04-2019 in php

Tags: php

how to change date format in php 
Sun 10-04-19 to 10-04-2019
please help, thank you,

this my code

```
    $content1="Sun 10-04-19"; 
    $newformat = strtotime($content1);
    echo date('d-m-Y',$newformat);
```

output

```
  25-04-2010
```

Comment: Your date is wrong. Sun isn't on 10th April. :|

Comment: Is 10 the year? 04 is month right? But then what is 19 that gets magically transformed to 25?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and specifying the [date format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
$content1 = "Sun 14-04-19";
// assuming the format is day-month-year 
$newformat = DateTime::createFromFormat('D d-m-y', $content1);
echo $newformat->format('d-m-Y');
```

Btw your date is invalid.

**Result:**

```
14-04-2019
```

Comment: thanks, but not work its give me output  14-04-2019

Comment: @KamleshJain that is because your date is invalid.. 10th April was Wednesday not Sunday

Comment: @KamleshJain change the format to this `d-m-y`. Masivuye Cokile is correct, the date is invalid.

Comment: OP wants 'Y' since it's 2010 in the expected output.